# Работа с socket в python

Tags: python, сокет

Написал модуль для получения ответа от php-fpm из socket. Но переодически в ответ попадают лишние данные, например в строку с датой добавляется лишние символы: 0a7/Jun/2017

```
import socket
import random
import errno
import select
import re

class FastCGIClient:
"""A Fast-CGI Client for Python"""

# private
__FCGI_VERSION = 1

__FCGI_ROLE_RESPONDER = 1
__FCGI_ROLE_AUTHORIZER = 2
__FCGI_ROLE_FILTER = 3

__FCGI_TYPE_BEGIN = 1
__FCGI_TYPE_ABORT = 2
__FCGI_TYPE_END = 3
__FCGI_TYPE_PARAMS = 4
__FCGI_TYPE_STDIN = 5
__FCGI_TYPE_STDOUT = 6
__FCGI_TYPE_STDERR = 7
__FCGI_TYPE_DATA = 8
__FCGI_TYPE_GETVALUES = 9
__FCGI_TYPE_GETVALUES_RESULT = 10
__FCGI_TYPE_UNKOWNTYPE = 11

__FCGI_HEADER_SIZE = 8

# request state
FCGI_STATE_SEND = 1
FCGI_STATE_ERROR = 2
FCGI_STATE_SUCCESS = 3

def __init__(self, host, port, timeout, keepalive):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.timeout = timeout
    if keepalive:
        self.keepalive = 1
    else:
        self.keepalive = 0
    self.sock = None
    self.requests = dict()

def __connect(self):
    try:
        if "sock" in self.host:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            socket.socket.setblocking(self.sock,0)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.sock.connect((self.host))
        else:

            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect((self.host, int(self.port)))
    except socket.error as msg:
        self.sock.close()
        self.sock = None
        print(repr(msg))
        return False
    return True

def __encodeFastCGIRecord(self, fcgi_type, content, requestid):
    length = len(content)
    return chr(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_VERSION) \
           + chr(fcgi_type) \
           + chr((requestid >> 8) & 0xFF) \
           + chr(requestid & 0xFF) \
           + chr((length >> 8) & 0xFF) \
           + chr(length & 0xFF) \
           + chr(0) \
           + chr(0) \
           + content

def __encodeNameValueParams(self, name, value):
    nLen = len(str(name))
    vLen = len(str(value))
    record = ''
    if nLen < 128:
        record += chr(nLen)
    else:
        record += chr((nLen >> 24) | 0x80) \
                  + chr((nLen >> 16) & 0xFF) \
                  + chr((nLen >> 8) & 0xFF) \
                  + chr(nLen & 0xFF)
    if vLen < 128:
        record += chr(vLen)
    else:
        record += chr((vLen >> 24) | 0x80) \
                  + chr((vLen >> 16) & 0xFF) \
                  + chr((vLen >> 8) & 0xFF) \
                  + chr(vLen & 0xFF)
    return record + str(name) + str(value)

def __decodeFastCGIHeader(self, stream):
    header = dict()
    header['version'] = ord(stream[0])
    header['type'] = ord(stream[1])
    header['requestId'] = (ord(stream[2]) << 8) + ord(stream[3])
    header['contentLength'] = (ord(stream[4]) << 8) + ord(stream[5])
    header['paddingLength'] = ord(stream[6])
    header['reserved'] = ord(stream[7])
    return header

def __decodeFastCGIRecord(self):
    length = FastCGIClient.__FCGI_HEADER_SIZE
    dataList = []
    recvLen = 0
    while length:
        try:
            header = self.sock.recv(length)
        except socket.error, e:
            if e[0] == errno.EAGAIN:
                header = select.select([self.sock], [], [])
                continue
            else:
                raise
        if not header:
            break
        else:
            dataList.append(header)
            dataLen = len(header)
            dataLen = len(header)
            length -= dataLen

    return ''.join(dataList)

def request(self, nameValuePairs={}, post=''):
    if not self.__connect():
        print('connect failure! please check your fasctcgi-server !!')
        return

    requestId = random.randint(1, (1 << 16) - 1)
    self.requests[requestId] = dict()
    request = ""
    beginFCGIRecordContent = chr(0) \
                             + chr(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_ROLE_RESPONDER) \
                             + chr(self.keepalive) \
                             + chr(0) * 5
    request += self.__encodeFastCGIRecord(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_TYPE_BEGIN,
                                          beginFCGIRecordContent, requestId)
    paramsRecord = ''
    if nameValuePairs:
        for (name, value) in nameValuePairs.iteritems():
            paramsRecord += self.__encodeNameValueParams(name, value)

    if paramsRecord:
        request += self.__encodeFastCGIRecord(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_TYPE_PARAMS, paramsRecord, requestId)
    request += self.__encodeFastCGIRecord(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_TYPE_PARAMS, '', requestId)

    request += self.__encodeFastCGIRecord(FastCGIClient.__FCGI_TYPE_STDIN, '', requestId)
    self.sock.send(request)
    self.requests[requestId]['state'] = FastCGIClient.FCGI_STATE_SEND
    self.requests[requestId]['response'] = ''
    return self.__waitForResponse(requestId)

def __waitForResponse(self, requestId):
    response = ''
    while True:
            resp = self.__decodeFastCGIRecord()
            response += str(resp)
            if not resp:
                    break
    return response
def __repr__(self):
    return "fastcgi connect host:{} port:{}".format(self.host, self.port)
```

Упорно не могу отловить где ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший способ разобраться: сделай дамп трафика через wireshark и пройдись руками по всем байтам.

`0х0a` это `'\n'` и скорее всего этот байт из предыдущей строки.

В работе со строками под Виндовс есть особенность, что LF может заменяться на CRLF в файловых объектах. Оттуда появляется лишний байт.

Еще стоит обратить внимание на то как передаются строки в FCGI. Разные реализации могут давать `\r` или `\r\n` или `\n`.

П.С. Для разбора этого протакола я бы воспользовался модулем `struct` а не `ord` и `chr`.